# binding nested array data to view- knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array called **simpleSearchResultsArray** in main viewModel -**QuoteSimpleSearchVM**.

The array **simpleSearchResultsArray** contains **SimpleSearchResults** objects.

Inside each **SimpleSearchResults** there is an object called **quoteDetailsObj** defined.
The data is added to the **quoteDetailsObj**. And the object **quoteDetailsObj** is bound to the view. 
I am not able to bind this nested array viewmodel to the view.
Here is the link for the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FENuV/29/

View code:

```
<div id="QdetailsDiv">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div><span>Sold to Account</span></div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtSoldToAccount" data-bind="value:SoldToAccount"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><span>Job Name</span></div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="txtQDJobName"  data-bind="value:jobName"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="unbind" id="unbindbutton"></input>
</div>
```

ViewModel code:

```
QuoteDetails = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.SoldToAccount = ko.observable();
    self.jobName = ko.observable();
};

function SimpleSearchResults() {
    var self = this;
    self.index = ko.observable();
    self.quoteDetailsObj= null; 

    self.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM = function (SimpleSearchResultsObj) {
        SimpleSearchResultsObj.quoteDetailsObj = ko.observable(new QuoteDetails()); 
        SimpleSearchResultsObj.quoteDetailsObj.SoldToAccount = ko.observable("SoldToAccount test");        
        SimpleSearchResultsObj.quoteDetailsObj.jobName = ko.observable("jobName test");
        ko.applyBindings(SimpleSearchResultsObj.quoteDetailsObj, document.getElementById("QdetailsDiv"));
    };
};

function QuoteSimpleSearchVM() {

    var self = this;
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray = ko.observableArray([]);

    var SimpleSearchResultsObj= new SimpleSearchResults();
    SimpleSearchResultsObj.index=ko.observable("1");
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray.push(SimpleSearchResultsObj);    

    var SimpleSearchResultsObj2= new SimpleSearchResults();
    SimpleSearchResultsObj2.index=ko.observable("2");
    self.simpleSearchResultsArray.push(SimpleSearchResultsObj2);    

};
 var obj= new QuoteSimpleSearchVM();
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#unbindbutton").click(function(){
        var element = $('#QdetailsDiv')[0];
        ko.cleanNode(element);
    });    

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(obj.simpleSearchResultsArray(), function (SimpleSearchResultsObj) {             
                if (SimpleSearchResultsObj.index() === "2") {
                    SimpleSearchResultsObj.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM(this);
                }
            });
});
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
SimpleSearchResultsObj.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM(this);
```

"this" is referring to the window, I don't think that's what you want to do. As I suppose you want to refer to the current "SimpleSearchResults", why not just use "self" in BindDataToQuotesDetailVm?

```
self.BindDataToQuotesDetailVM = function () {
    self.quoteDetailsObj = new QuoteDetails(); 
    self.quoteDetailsObj.SoldToAccount("SoldToAccount test");        
    self.quoteDetailsObj.jobName("jobName test");
    ko.applyBindings(self.quoteDetailsObj, document.getElementById("QdetailsDiv"));
};
```

Furthermore, what you're doing in "BindDataToQuotesDetailVm" is wrong. "QuoteDetails" declares observable, and you're reassigning new observable in the function. It won't work. You have to give a value to the existing observables (see above). Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynV35/